# What happens if I accidentally interrupted iOS software update on iphone

Tags: ios, iphone

I was updating my iPhone and I accidentally pressed the home and lock button together thus interrupting the update. It has directed me to a link where I was instructed to connect the iPhone to iTunes and download the update. (I clicked update; not restore, of course.)
My question is will there be any harm to my data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer

**No**. If your iPhone works after performing a force reboot (holding the Home button and the sleep button for a few seconds), **you are good to go**.

---

### Explanation

iOS downloads the delta update first and starts the update process. You may have interrupted iOS while extracting the update files or checking them for consistency.

---

### Additional information

The update will probably appear in Settings > General > Storage. Feel free to install the update using your iPhone or a computer with iTunes installed.

Did this answer your question?